# Creating a sub class from a super class ?

Tags: c++, subclass, extend

I'm trying to extend this class

```
template <class T> class dynamic_array
```

This does not work

```
class merge_sort : public dynamic_array
```

What is the proper way to extend the class?

Comment: `dynamic_array` is a template, not a type. You can only inherit from types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to provide an argument for the template. If you want to use a fixed argument, say `int`, then you would do:

```
class merge_sort : public dynamic_array< int >
```

If you instead want to keep the extended class as generic, you would do:

```
template< class T >
class merge_sort : public dynamic_array< T >
```

Note that merge sort is an algorithm, and as such it would be better off as a free function than as an object. According to OOP, you should ask *is `merge_sort` a `dynamic_array`?* For me the answer sounds as **no**, so I would do this instead:

```
template< class T >
void merge_sort( dynamic_array< T >& array ){ ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class T>
class merge_sort : public dynamic_array<T>
```

The template Arguments have to be specified to the base class you can however drive form a  fully qualifed base class.

```
class merge_sort : public dynamic_array<int>
```